# Setting custom text on top of bar chart

Tags: ios-charts

Hello I want to achieve the following.

[image: example]

So far everything went good by using the docs. However, I can't seem to set a value on top like € 230 or € 70. When I use the

```
barChartView.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = true
```

Because it sets the value of the bar charts ( 70, 30 etc)

Is it possible to do this? :)

Answer (score 1):

each dataSet has a value formater, use it to format your value like below should be enough:

```
set1.valueFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
set1.valueFormatter.negativePrefix = @"€ ";
set1.valueFormatter.positivePrefix = @"€ ";
```